# Mixing Symfonisk high/low-mid output channels

Tags: audio, circuit-design, dac, mixed-signal

So i've been messing with this issue for a couple of months and it's just that my electronics knowledge isn't reaching far enough.

I have a Symfonisk speaker by Ikea, which outputs a low and high/mid signal to two internal speakers which I want to connect to two ceiling speakers.

As said, the DAC (TI PCM5101A) is in a high/low channel setup which outputs two. My first thought was to just cross/combine the channels. But that shorts the DAC and shuts down. Lesson one learned.

After search a bit further i found that i could combine the channels by by-passing the capacitors: https://www.diyaudio.com/forums/digital-line-level/349202-getting-audio-signal-ikea-symfonisk-sonos.html

I tried this method and was surprised to hear a great sound coming out of my speakers. But all until the system tried to deliver some low. The sound gets muffled and a bit numb when there is some bass in the the track. Sounds like side-chain compression. Not sure why.

So my second option would be some sort of passive mixing circuit, where i simply combine the channels in a single mixed output. But I'm not sure how to approach this since 'combining' the channels does make the DAC shutdown.

What would the right approach be?

Comment: As a designer, I would want a full specification and circuit diagram of the DAC output and ditto for the speakers along with some statement from the manufacturer that you can add extra speakers as you propose. At the moment this question falls into a category that is likely to get it closed - designer's will not take guesses about what a pre-designed bit of electronics is capable of doing when modified without full disclosure of technical information.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your taken time. This probably be more in-place in a DIY part of SE but not sure where though. I think I'm more in the running for a general purpose high/mid-low mixing circuit which I'm not able to find.

Comment: Ceiling speakers cannot be especially massive. Is it possible that they do not stand bass sounds you drive to them? You should measure something to see what's going on in volts and hertzes. In this site we are not interested in terms such as beautiful. Cool numbers rule.